# Minimum and maximum of a field in cakephp and mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, aggregate-functions, max, min

I am trying to build a search function for a cakephp and mysql site. Selecting different parameters like price of the product or the length triggers an ajax call which returns the number of matching results. I want to extend the returned results with the the minimum and maximum values for the lengths and prices. I tried doing this, http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1004813660 . Using the first 4 finds is too time consuming. The last one functions locally, but I get the error;

1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),,...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`

remotely, due to  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY being on.

Is it possible to use the last option with some improvements, or can I switch off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by changing the way I was searching. Instead of doing queries in the conditions that would lead to joins, I explicitly did the searching with where. I had things like,

```
$conditions = array('Brand.name LIKE'=> '%bla%');
```

which I replaced it with

```
 $condtions = array('Yacht.brand_name LIKE' => '%bla%');
```

I had to restructure the database a bit, but the tradeoff between speed and database normalization is one I can live with.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you well, you want to get in a single request

- MIN(Yacht.price) as min_price
- MAX(Yacht.price) as max_price
- MIN(Yacht.long) as min_length
- MAX(Yacht.long) as max_length

right ?

For this, you do not need any "Group By" clause. MIN and MAX functions are already aggregations functions. But nothing prevents you from using multiple aggregations functions in a single request.

Have you tried simply doing this ?

```
$stats = $this->Yacht->find(array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'fields' => array(
        'MIN(Yacht.price) as min_price',
        'MAX(Yacht.price) as max_price',
        'MIN(Yacht.long) as min_length',
        'MAX(Yacht.long) as max_length'
     )
    )
);
```

By the way, according to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first), there seems to be quite a lot of redundancy in your original code. "find('first', array(...))" by itself ensures you get only one result hence, there is no need to specify "'limit' => 1" in the request nor "order" clause as there would be only one field anyway :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try that. But while it works on the local site, it does not on the remote site. This is due to the "mixing of group columns" mysql error. See the last query ($allValues). Thanks for the heads up on the redundancy.

Comment: @Awemo can you give us you MySQL version ? Is that 5.x ?

Comment: and what is you local MySQL version ? Is it the same ?

Comment: Well, don't know if this matters. I have 5.0.8 on my development enviroment.

Comment: According to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23417 it *seems* that it actually is a bug on your local version. Thus, I feel your local version is behaving in a more logical way. I use 5.5 and do not encounter this issue. Can you consider upgrading ?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot upgrade. I don't quite understand which enviroment has the bug?

Comment: Oddly enough, this is the local version.

Answer (score 1):

The way to set server modes can be found here... If you read the top of the document it will tell you how to set the server mode defaults:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html

However, I'm not sure that is necessary to get to your solution. I think your query is running for a long time because you need a different group by in your code and less queries. You should be able to use a logical group by that will maximize your primary key (index):

```
'group' => 'Yacht.id'
```

So you have one query returning everything:

```
$this->Yacht->find('first', array(
'conditions' => $conditions,
'fields' => array('MAX(Yacht.price) as max_price', 'MIN(Yacht.price) as min_price', ...)
'group' => 'Yacht.id'
'order' => '...'));
```

Comment: I will take a look at switching off the sql_mode. I had however tried to group by. However, due to the fact that the first result is returned, it will give me only the result with respect to what I define in order by. For example, if I order by Yacht.price ASC, it gives the whole row which corresponds to the minimum possible price. The other parameters are not the result that is expected.